# What part of the Set-Cookie should be sent to the server?

Tags: http, cookies, winhttp

I have this http request:

```
>     Header contents:
>     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>     Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store
>     Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 08:55:45 GMT
>     Content-Length: 22049
>     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>     Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 08:54:46 GMT
>     P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
>     Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>     Set-Cookie: uaid=d796f99cd2d0412896d89ff49e17f558; domain=login.live.com;secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
>     Set-Cookie: MSPRequ=lt=1563353746&co=1&id=N; secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly=;version=1
>     Set-Cookie: MSCC=185.114.139.243-UA; expires=Mon, 10-Aug-2020 08:55:46 GMT;domain=login.live.com;secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly=
> ;version=1
>     Set-Cookie: OParams=11DYc12zw!m0m7KBb!DgFPYsJXqpdnsnm6nN3KgjlWTBX2lFFtVrtpWXroTonZhmkMvYlU!f3nP2nNmxl1e06ODEOqVKryMr2c8oUmEwI6X!pkrwGqp*d3yzT3VgKmGYMM8kan2MCPifbPjx!8Ww3OhjXTuJz6OCXClnzjw6BP2S8xT8jhvTPxOwiLO1aKqS65f2TXcEHLKmR7yHPQp773y8M$;
> domain=login.live.com;secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
>     Set-Cookie: MSPOK=$uuid-3a02e0a2-6a86-42f0-ab2a-d8252a1a9567; domain=login.live.com;secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
>     X-Frame-Options: deny
>     PPServer: PPV: 30 H: BL02PF05B1B33B1 V: 0
>     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
>     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

What part of the Set-Cookie should be sent to the server?

I didn't find something about MSPRequ, MSCC, MSPOK. Thank for your answer.

Comment: That's not a request, it's a response. Set-Cookie is sent in the response, in the request you send just Cookie (with just the name and the value).

Comment: How can I understand what the name and value I may send?

Comment: 2K World, you need to say what language you're using to send the data to the server. You can send any named values inside of the cookie as that's part of the client-side. More information is needed to know what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I send GET request to login.live.com using WinHttp C++ and when I open the page that was downloaded, I see "Your browser blocked cookie". Documents for WinHttp states that cookie should be processed automatically. I decided to try to process cookies manually.